# How to pass in a mocked HttpClient in a .NET test?

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, dotnet-httpclient, microsoft-fakes

I have a service which uses `Microsoft.Net.Http` to retrieve some `Json` data. Great!

Of course, I don't want my unit test hitting the actual server (otherwise, that's an integration test).

Here's my service ctor (which uses dependency injection...)

```
public Foo(string name, HttpClient httpClient = null)
{
...
}
```

I'm not sure how I can mock this with ... say .. `Moq` or `FakeItEasy`.

I want to make sure that when my service calls `GetAsync` or `PostAsync` .. then i can fake those calls.

Any suggestions how I can do that?

I'm -hoping- i don't need to make my own Wrapper .. cause that's crap :( Microsoft can't have made an oversight with this, right?

(yes, it's easy to make wrappers .. i've done them before ... but it's the point!)

Comment: _"I'm -hoping- i don't need to make my own Wrapper"_ - how many of the `HttpClient`'s methods and properties do you use? It can usually prove useful to create an interface for those, which you can then mock.

Comment: (Like I mentioned in the OP) Agreed - it's easy and simple ... but I would have though that I shouldn't have to? This is something that should be core .. right? Is this my only option?

Comment: As far as i know you could stub those calls if they would be virtual. As they aren't, I'd assume you need to write a wrapper (which is the cleaner way imo).

Comment: In that case see [Non Interface dependent Mocking Frameworks for C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230225/non-interface-dependent-mocking-frameworks-for-c-sharp), which I found through _".net mock not virtual methods without interface"_. The accepted answer advises to use [.NET Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/), the only .NET mocking framework I know of that works without virtual methods.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can replace the core HttpMessageHandler with a fake one.  Something that looks like this...

```
public class FakeResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Uri, HttpResponseMessage> _FakeResponses = new Dictionary<Uri, HttpResponseMessage>();

    public void AddFakeResponse(Uri uri, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
    {
        _FakeResponses.Add(uri, responseMessage);
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_FakeResponses.ContainsKey(request.RequestUri))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(_FakeResponses[request.RequestUri]);
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound) { RequestMessage = request });
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can create a client that will use the fake handler.

```
var fakeResponseHandler = new FakeResponseHandler();
fakeResponseHandler.AddFakeResponse(new Uri("http://example.org/test"), new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));

var httpClient = new HttpClient(fakeResponseHandler);

var response1 = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://example.org/notthere");
var response2 = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://example.org/test");

Assert.Equal(response1.StatusCode,HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
Assert.Equal(response2.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Comment: Nice solution to an interesting problem.  Literally does everything except send HTTP over the wire.

Comment: Your example will not compile as it is. You need to using Task.FromResult to return your HttpResponseMessage instances.

Comment: @Ananke The async keyword on the SendAsync method does that magic for you.

Comment: I like it! Can I suggest a small improvement? In the SendAsync method where you return the value from the dictionary, I made it so that you attach the original request as well in case you want to inspect that, like so:
var response = _FakeResponses[request.RequestUri];
response.RequestMessage = request;
return response;
Doing this allowed this solution to meet my needs nicely. Thanks!

Comment: @CraigBrett Yup, that makes sense

Comment: Does anyone else think this is much more unnecessarily complicated than having an `IHttpClient` interface to mock?

Comment: How would you handle POSTs and PUTs with this method?

Comment: Turns out POSTs call to DelegatingHandler.SendAsync despite the method name:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106664/intercept-c-sharp-httpclient-getasync

Comment: If you are looking for a more complete version of this we created a ChaosHandler here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/Middleware/ChaosHandler.cs that can also inject random failures.

Answer (score 19):

I know that this is an old question but I stumbled with it during a search on this topic and found a very nice solution to make testing `HttpClient` easier.

It is available via nuget:

https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp

```
PM> Install-Package RichardSzalay.MockHttp
```

Here is a quick look on the usage:

```
var mockHttp = new MockHttpMessageHandler();

// Setup a respond for the user api (including a wildcard in the URL)
mockHttp.When("http://localost/api/user/*")
        .Respond("application/json", "{'name' : 'Test McGee'}"); // Respond with JSON

// Inject the handler or client into your application code
var client = new HttpClient(mockHttp);

var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localost/api/user/1234");
// or without await: var response = client.GetAsync("http://localost/api/user/1234").Result;

var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// No network connection required
Console.Write(json); // {'name' : 'Test McGee'}
```

More info on the github project page.
Hope this can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I would just make a small change to [@Darrel Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6819/darrel-miller)'s answer, which is using *Task.FromResult* to avoid the warning about an async method expecting an await operator.

```
public class FakeResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Uri, HttpResponseMessage> _FakeResponses = new Dictionary<Uri, HttpResponseMessage>();

    public void AddFakeResponse(Uri uri, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
    {
        _FakeResponses.Add(uri, responseMessage);
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_FakeResponses.ContainsKey(request.RequestUri))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(_FakeResponses[request.RequestUri]);
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound) { RequestMessage = request });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be cautious using that technique in any environment that is performance sensitive as it could cause a thread switch for no benefit.  If you are really concerned about the warning, then just remove the async keyword and use Task.FromResult.

Comment: If the implementation is not task based it is better to return Task.FromResult and remove the async keyword instead of using Task.Run. return Task.FromResult(response);

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx#shims), especially at the `Shims`-section. With them, you're able to modify the behaviours of your HttpClient itself. Prerequisite is, that you're using VS Premium or Ultimate.

Comment: I don't have access to those two expensive editions.