# How to Unit Test ASP.NET CORE controller with MSTEST and add Fakes

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mstest

I have an `MVC` project in ASP.NET CORE. I have added a class library and added testing frameworks in `project.json`.

The test methods seems to execute and run. But I have scenarios where I need to use shims and stubs.

For example Web Client or a an interface method. I am unable to add fakes for `dll's` in ASP.NET CORE. How do I do it? Is there any method to shim methods like Web client in core?

Dependencies added:

```
"dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "dotnet-test-mstest": "1.0.1-preview",
    "MSTest.TestFramework": "1.0.0-preview"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create mocks, you can use `"Moq": "4.6.25-alpha"` package. It works with .NET core and is what the ASP.NET team uses.

Following articles gives an example of how you can use mocks to do unit testing. In the article `Xunit` is used but it shouldn't be that different with MSTest.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/testing.html

Also you can take a look at the `MusicStore` sample's xunit tests:
https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/1.0.0/test/MusicStore.Test

Comment: can you provide an example of mocking the webclient or httpclient method which is used to get api data which can be mocked??

Comment: I am not clear. Are you using httpclient or webclient inside of your controller's action? If yes, then you could probably take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22264503/1184056

Comment: I am actually using a httpcline tinside the controller to make an api call from an another service hosted outside the domain.. So inorder to fake this , i need some solution.. my controller from which i am using the httpClient is not implemented using an interface or wrapper.. i am asking if there is any possible solution to Shim the httpClient..

Comment: I don't think its possible to shim the httpclient if we look at its type. The earlier link seems to be a good(or maybe the only) solution here.

Comment: @KiranChalla, at the moment, there is no nuget package for dotnet-test-mstest that would support NetStandard1.6 - we only have an pre-release version of this library for .NETFramework and .NETCoreApp

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) instead of currently used HttpClient. It has testing capabilities.
http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/testable-http/,
E.g.

```
using (var httpTest = new HttpTest()) {
        // Flurl is now in test mode 
       sut.CallThingThatUsesFlurlHttp(); // HTTP calls are faked!
}
```